# Fading in a div after a delay

Tags: javascript, html, time, delay, fade

I'm new to javascript so I'm struggling with the basics...

I'm using this delay to bring in a div but i want to fade the div in as part of this function (not just have the box appear)

```
function show() {

AB = document.getElementById('div_with_text');

AB.style.display = 'inline';
}

setTimeout("show()", 3000);
```

Can any one help with this?

I've tried adding things like:

```
$(function(){  
  $('#div_with_text').fadeIn('slow');  
});
```

but I don't know the language well enough to get it to work...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Hey Lobo, I have a text box that appears on my home page after the delay script above - this work fine but I would prefer the box to fade in. So I'm asking what do i need to add to the delay code to fade the box in after the delay? hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 2):

Is your DIV hidden in the first place? If not, that is your problem. Your are trying to open an already opened door.

Your code is also incorrect, even if you hide the DIV, this will not work. It should have been `setTimeout(show, 3000);`

With the JavaScript code (`setTimeout`) you have provided, 3 seconds after the page loads, you are trying to display the DIV. Did you notice that the DIV was already there and never 'appeared' after 3 seconds as you expected?

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/BLPTq/2/ - just click run and see.

---

To make it work, hide the DIV first and then call the setTimeout or the jQuery method. Example - http://jsfiddle.net/zeXyG/ - just click run and see. Check the CSS `display:none;`

OR, if you don't want to hide it with CSS, just call `hide()` before calling `fadeIn()`

```
$('#div_with_text').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/zeXyG/1/

---

As per your comment below. Add `delay()` to the call like shown below

```
$('#div_with_text').hide(); // this or use css to hide the div
$('#div_with_text').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');
```

2 seconds after the page loads, this will hide the div and then fade in slowly. Look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/zeXyG/3/) carefully.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to explain that. A combination of the two is exactly what I'm after. 
The div is NOT hidden to begin with, without any of this code it would just be onscreen when the page loads. So what I need to do is combine what you have shown me to achieve a fadein after 3 seconds... I don't know the correct syntax to do this but i'll give it a go combining what's there - trial and error!? I don't suppose you know?

Comment: Didn't the last example with `hide().fadeIn()` work? I added `delay()` . May be that is what you want.

Comment: Why is nothing simple today...! when i go to upload the page(html) with your code in (which looks spot on btw) i get a message that says "the documents current encoding cannot save all of the characters. you may want to change to utf-8...etc"... so it wont let me upload. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried it... but i dunno what's going wrong nothing appears. this page is the last place i got to that worked...I've been trying to use your code to replace the delay here but i must be doing something wrong... http://www.pierrecarr.com/phase4/index.html  im going to strip the page down to replicate your code and get that working then work from there...

Comment: Read my answer carefully, you will see where you are going wrong. Also, try to keep all javascript code at the top in script tag. All the best.

Comment: will do... i appreciate all the help and will post again if i really get stuck or better still once i fix the problem - Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

The `fadeIn` method will only work if you load the jQuery library on your page.  Without that, the method will not work since it isn't part of native Javascript.

Once you have loaded jQuery, [that method](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) will work as your syntax is correct.

Comment: thanks for the reply mate i'm using     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> at the top of my code... will that do it? 
my code seems to ignore the fade function request once the 'show' has completed. this makes me think the fade should be called earlier?